# Gap when using tikz angles

Tags: tikz-pgf

When i try to draw the angles alpha and theta using the following code i get some weird gaps or overhangs on the angles. This is my first time using angles with tikz so i have no idea if i did something wrong.
Thanks for the help!

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (test2) at (0,0);
        \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[right] (test1) {x};
        \draw[->, thick] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[above] {y};
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (2, 2) node[below] (test3) {r};
        \draw pic[pic text = {$\theta$}, draw, -, angle eccentricity=1.3, angle radius = 15] {angle = test1--test2--test3};
        \draw[dashed] (2, 2) -- (2, {2 + 1.25}) node[] (dashed) {};
        \draw (2, 2) -- ({2+1}, {2 + 0.5}) node[] (bold) {};
        \draw pic[pic text = {$\alpha$}, draw, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius = 30] {angle = bold--test3--dashed};

        \draw[dashed] ({sqrt(8)}, 0) arc[start angle = 0, end angle = 90, radius ={sqrt(8)}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:halbachwinkel}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gaps at angles are caused by use nodes name for coordinates defining angle. If you replace those nodes by `\coordinate`, all will work fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,    % new
                quotes}                 % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=west,
              angle radius = 8mm, angle eccentricity=1},
arr/.style = {cap=round,-Straight Barb},
                        ]
\coordinate (test2) at (0,0);
% axix
\draw[arr] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[right] (test1) {x};
\draw[arr] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[above] {y};
% vector
\draw[arr, thick] (test2) -- (2, 2) 
    coordinate[label={[inner sep=1ex]270:r}] (test3);
% angle theta  
\pic[ang, "$\theta$"] {angle = test1--test2--test3};
% circle
\draw[densely dashed] ({sqrt(8)},0) arc (0:90:{sqrt(8)});
% angle alpha
\draw[dashed]   (test3) -- ++ (0,1.25) coordinate (dashed) {};
\draw           (test3) -- ++ (+1,0.5) coordinate (bold) {};
\pic[ang, "$\alpha$"] {angle = bold--test3--dashed};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't get your solution to work. It seems like there were some errors when you pasted your code here like some brackets missing maybe? I really don't know

Comment: @user2464637, you are right. At formatting code I by accident erase two closed braces in command for vector. Now this error is corrected.